# GCP datastore emulator import has broken references

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

When trying to import into the Datastore Emulator, all the data is imported correctly, but the key references are wrong somehow.

The procedure I'm following to import is the one from [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/emulator-export-import) following an export from the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#exporting_all_entities).

I've included a screenshot of the situation from the Datastore viewer as otherwise it's hard to understand.

It appears as though the key references (blue arrow) contain the correct kind and ID, as the Datastore viewer is pulling those out (orange arrow) and they are correct, but the entity it references has a different main entity key (e.g. red arrow though obviously for a different entity) which are all in a slightly different format (they have a common prefix and two hyphens in them).

It seems as though the key encoding is done in a subtly inconsistent manner in the emulator versus in the live datastore, but I've not been able to find any documentation about this anywhere.

Running code and connecting to the emulator with the client library shows that all the references have the correct IDs as well (I'm not even sure if you can see the string keys using the Ruby client). Trying to use the client to reset the references by setting the same ID and saving to hopefully regenerate the keys didn't work either.

[image]

Comment: One of the subjects of meta question *[Users doing Google first-level customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399137/users-doing-google-first-level-customer-support)*.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your app is working fine but you are just concerned about the encodings. If so, there is nothing to worry.

> It seems as though the key encoding is done in a subtly inconsistent manner in the emulator versus in the live datastore, but I've not been able to find any documentation about this anywhere.

The way the keys get encoded has changed at some point. The datastore viewer that comes with the SDK I believe still uses the old style. The API was even enhanced to support decoding from the old style, you can refer

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/3293

to for more details. I found that the newer encoding is more compact than the old encoding. I believe the new encoding doesn't include the app/project id into the encoding which makes sense because that information belongs to the entire database and not to each specific key.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I’ll investigate that next week and see if I can figure anything out. Unfortunately though, our app isn’t working fine as all the references are broken. The references are in the new encoding but all the entities seem to have keys in the old encoding.